# How can I combine multiple CSV files that share an identical column into a new CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

So I have multiple csv files of data that I want to put into one main file. Each CSV file has two columns, the first column has labelled bins, the second column represents the count of data points that fell in those bins. I want to combine each csv file in a way that enables me to make a heatmap or 2d histogram, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-combine-multiple-csv-files-with-8-lines-of-code-265183e0854/) but it didnt have the intended effect. The first lines of output end up looking like this, just the first few lines

```
Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 0,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 1,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 2,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 3,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 4,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 5,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 6,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 7,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 8,Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 9
"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0,"(-10, -9]",0
"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0,"(-9, -8]",0
"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0,"(-8, -7]",0
"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0,"(-7, -6]",0
"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0,"(-6, -5]",0
"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0,"(-5, -4]",0
"(-4, -3]",0,"(-4, -3]",41,"(-4, -3]",6,"(-4, -3]",20,"(-4, -3]",0,"(-4, -3]",0,"(-4, -3]",0,"(-4, -3]",5,"(-4, -3]",2,"(-4, -3]",1
"(-3, -2]",21,"(-3, -2]",52,"(-3, -2]",38,"(-3, -2]",52,"(-3, -2]",1,"(-3, -2]",0,"(-3, -2]",0,"(-3, -2]",68,"(-3, -2]",22,"(-3, -2]",4
"(-2, -1]",13,"(-2, -1]",80,"(-2, -1]",120,"(-2, -1]",51,"(-2, -1]",34,"(-2, -1]",36,"(-2, -1]",4,"(-2, -1]",81,"(-2, -1]",40,"(-2, -1]",8
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get it to only add the labelling column just once instead of each time.

Here is an example of one of the CSV files I am trying to do this to, again just the first few lines

```
Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 0
"(-10, -9]",0
"(-9, -8]",0
"(-8, -7]",0
"(-7, -6]",0
"(-6, -5]",0
"(-5, -4]",0
"(-4, -3]",0
"(-3, -2]",24
"(-2, -1]",67
"(-1, 0]",126
"(0, 1]",171
"(1, 2]",339
```

Finally here is the code I am using,

```
def combine_to_master(coordmastername, csvdir):
    os.chdir(csvdir)
    ext = "csv"
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(ext))]
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], sort=True, axis=1)
    combined_csv.to_csv(coordmastername + ".csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: What output do you want? "combine" isn't really sufficient: there's an infinite number of ways to "combine" data. Do you want to sum each respective coordinate bin?

Comment: Ah yes I would like to have each column from all my CSVs in this new CSV but with only one column that has the bin labels. I have that, but all the columns except the first are blank. but they are named which is whats got me confused.

Comment: do you have different names `Counts for time interval 0`, `Counts for time interval 1` in files or you have the same name `Counts` in all files? For different names could work `df = pd.merge(df1, df2)`. For the same names you may need `df['Counts 0'] = df1['Counts']` `df['Counts 1'] = df2['Counts']`

Comment: You just want one *long* csv - with two columns, each file appended to the end of the previous?

Comment: I recommend you start with just one bin, and like 2 or 3 files as the example for your question. Keep this short and simple. It's still not clear what you want as an end product...

Comment: So I refined my question a bit, @Furas, I think that you may be onto something with that suggestion.

Comment: and @wwii not quite, I want a CSV file that has the same number of rows as each constituent file but a new column for the Counts for time interval x.

Comment: @MattMessersmith I just want to prevent that duplicate column from being written to the file. I feel like I am way overthinking this.

Comment: Don't try to do it with a list comprehension. Use a *regular* for loop, you will have more control.  How big are the files? And does each file have the same *bins*?

Comment: Okay I will try out using proper for loops. The files are about 110 lines each with two columns. Each file has the same bins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get first dataframe and later merge with new dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Bin': [1,2,3], 'Counts 1': [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Bin': [1,2,3], 'Counts 2': [7,8,9]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Bin': [1,2,3], 'Counts 3': [1,2,3]})

df = df1

for new_df in [df2, df3]:
    df = pd.merge(df, new_df)

print(df)
```

Result

```
   Bin  Counts 1  Counts 2  Counts 3
0    1         4         7         1
1    2         5         8         2
2    3         6         9         3
```

Comment: Okay this seems like it should work, but it throws an error. pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False. I glanced at the documentation then and I am not sure. Does this mean there could be something wrong with how I am writing the csv files?

Comment: it seems you don't have `Coordinate Bins` in all files or you read it in wrong way and create `Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 0` as single column. You should check `print( df.columns )` or `print( df.dtypes )` for all dataframes.

Comment: I tried specifying the 'left_on' and 'left_index' as '"Coordinate bins"' and it threw a new error 'TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' coming from deep in the pandas library, but originating at this line where I call the merge 'combined_csv = pd.merge(combined_csv, pd.read_csv(csv_to_merge), left_on="Coordinate Bins", left_index=True)'

Comment: as I said - probably you read it in wrong way and it doesn't create column `"Coordinate bins"` but treats all data as one column with long name `"Coordinate Bins,Counts for time interval 0"`. First you have to check what you have after reading files -  `print( df.columns )` or `print( df.dtypes )`

Comment: okay I tried your suggestion and I get the following 'Index(['Coordinate Bins', 'Counts for time interval 0'], dtype='object')
Index(['Coordinate Bins', 'Counts for time interval 1'], dtype='object')' and so on. Ah I just saw your last. I think that could be the issue but Im not entirely sure If I am reading this output right, it seems to be saying I do have two columns, and the datatype is object.

Comment: did you assign first dataframe directly - see `df = df1` in my code. It will not merge to empty dataframe

Comment: I did not I messed that part up. It seems to work exactly as intended now. Thank you so much furas, this little problem has had me confused for a whole day now.